# Result of function into a new colum

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to adjust a column of data, currently the column contains a postal code and the city (example of one of the 10000 records) `9352BE Amsterdam`, i found a function to seperate it into `9352BE` and `Amsterdam`. But i have trouble storing the first half of the string(`9352BE` is the result of my function + 9999 other results) into a new column that i made for it(all 10.000 of the records are split, i just need to store them all). 
some info: 
the function is called `SPLIT_STR`.... 
The column with the concatinated data is called `pc_wp`....
and the column i want the results in is called `POSTAL_CODE1`.

here is what i came up with:

```
 update funda.estate
 set POSTAL_CODE1 = (SELECT SPLIT_STR(pc_wp, ' ', 1) as Postal_code
 FROM funda.estate);
```

this function strips the `Amsterdam` off the string and results in only the postal code that i wanna store, in this example being `9352BE`.

I've tried to put it into multiple syntaxes but none seem to give any results sadly. how can i store all the results from executing the function into my new column?

Comment: show us sample data and expected result after update.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Will do next time, i thought the 'example' would have been adequate but guess i should give more/better info next time, will look out for it and read what you linked, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your database (schema) is called `funda` and your table is named `estate`. Also that where you describe "tables" `pc_wp` and `POSTAL_CODE1` you mean "columns".

```
UPDATE funda.estate SET POSTAL_CODE1 = SPLIT_STR(pc_wp, ' ', 1);
```

Comment: Yes i ment columns , updated the main post on that :), this worked, thanks a bunch, did try this aswell, but then stupidly enough with a select statement behind the = sign *blushes* thanks a bunch!